# Append JS code to a Webpack module

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, bundle, commonjs

We have a legacy library – bunch of JavaScript files that are written ***without any module definitions*** and which must be loaded in a certain order to work properly (e.g. somewhere the code modifies the prototypes of objects declared in other files etc.)

I have a React component that needs to have the same scope with these files.

When I use `require` for each file, Webpack creates a different scope for every file (part of a library) and files don't have access to each other. Moreover, I cannot access anything from my React component and the final bundle works incorrectly.

The worst solution is to manually move everything into the React component file in correct order. But then the file will have >30kloc and I do not like it.

Are there any other ways in Webpack to append the code from 10 files *in correct order* and so that they have the same scope as my React component?

Comment: Your options, that I can see, are the following: a) refactor your existing files to be in a module format. The simplest rewrite would be to CommonJS, imo. b) make things global. c) merge all the files into one file. I would go with a). Nice Pudge btw. Actually let me try something. There may be a simpler solution.

Comment: Ok, so, no, these are your viable options.